# Use two methods of the same name in different .js files 

Tags: javascript

I have two methods with the same name, for different purposes in 2 different .js files. How can I use those methods on same page?

In Count.js:

```
function add()
{
// some manipulation doing here
}
```

In PriceImplement.js

```
Function add()
{
// some manipulation doing here
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should get into the habit of namespacing your JavaScript-files:

//Count.js:

```
var Count = {
  add: function add() {
  },
  [additional methods in the Count object]
};
```

// PriceImpl.js

```
var Price = {
  add: function add () {
  },
  [additional methods for the Price implementation]
};
```

Then call methods like `Namespace.method`, i.e. `Price.add()`

Comment: Don't forget to **not** use a trailing comma after the last function/property! Otherwise you'll be quarreling with IE. And just to add: Machine is using [named function expressions](http://yura.thinkweb2.com/named-function-expressions/#named-expr) here, which makes debugging a bit easier.

Answer (score 10):

If they're both defined using function declarations, like

```
function iHaveTheSameNameAsAnotherFunction(params) {
    …
}
```

then you can't. The second declaration will simply overwrite the first one.

Comment: is there any way to implement? can i create class in javascript and use them?

Comment: @Pankaj: Can you change one of those files (or both, so you can change the function name)?

Comment: @@ thanks Marcel...i can change function name.but can i create class in javascript and use them?

Comment: @Pankaj: Yes, see Machine's answer.

Comment: Are you sure? Or will functions in the same file call their respective function and functions in the other file the other respective function?