# call a specific javascript function when multiple same name function are in memory

Tags: javascript

I need to call specific js function. The problem is many time runtime situation can come where another js file may contain same name function. But i need to be specific that which function i am suppose to call. 
 Function overloading is not my solution.

Thanks and regards,
Tanmay

Comment: possible duplicate of [use two same name method in different .js files ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492636/use-two-same-name-method-in-different-js-files)

Comment: What do you mean by “function overloading”? Function cloning?

Answer (score 10):

you're going to have to do some reorganization of your resources and use namespacing where you can.

if you have a method named `saySomething` defined twice, you would move one of them to an object (whichever suits your needs better).

```
var myNS = new (function() {

    this.saySomething = function() {
        alert('hello!');
    };

})();
```

and the other defintion can be moved into a different object or even left alone.

```
function saySomething() {
    alert('derp!');
}
```

you can now call the `saySomething` method like

```
saySomething();      // derp!
myNS.saySomething(); // hello!
```

edit: since it was brought up in comments, this

```
var myNS = {
    saySomething: function() {
        alert('hello!');
    }
};
```

is equivalent to the first code block, in simpler form (if i'm remembering correctly).

Comment: Good answer, but why aren't you using [object literal notation](http://www.wait-till-i.com/2006/02/16/show-love-to-the-object-literal/)?

Comment: @Marcel Korpel habit i guess. typically when i create an object there are "private" variables, which are not available with literal notation (or I don't know how to do them).

Comment: You're right, but I like the [YUI Module Pattern](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2007/06/12/module-pattern/) more. Especially to a newbie, a `new` object created as a singleton using a self-executing anonymous function can be overwhelming and particularly confusing. Moreover, this answers the question, but it gives way more information than needed for purposes the OP asked about. So +1 for providing a correct answer, -1 for providing a way too verbose answer (though I have to admit it's never too soon to learn good practice).

Answer (score 3):

At least in firefox, when you have two functions with the same name, the second will overwrite the first one.

So, you can't call the first one.

Try it:

```
function a() {alert(1);}
function a() {alert(2);}
a(); // alerts '2'
```

See in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SxAhT/).

Comment: Not only in Firefox; in *every* Javascript engine of *every* browser. You can't even do this conditionally, as the outcome will be unpredictable. E.g., see [this code](http://jsbin.com/iwifi3/edit): in several browsers (at least in Chrome and Opera), the first function declaration is always overwritten by the second, regardless of the condition.

Comment: is there any way to let the second function to call the first function?

Comment: This pattern gives an error in Firefox v.83: `Uncaught SyntaxError: redeclaration of function a`.  But if you put the two function declarations in different scripts then it seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

In javascript, similarly named functions automatically override previous function defined with the exact same name.

Let's say your page includes 1.js and 2.js and both of them define the same function, for example say, display(). In this case, based on which js file is included the last, the definition of 'display()' in that file will override all other prior  definitions.

Answer (score 1):

I use function scope to limit the scope of variables and functions

Here is an example:

```
// existing function in JavaScript
function one() {

 console.log('one');   
}

one(); // outputs one

// inserting new JavaScript
(function() { // anonymous function wrapper
'use strict'; // ECMAScript-5

   function one() {

     console.log('two');   
   } 


   one(); // outputs two

})(); // end of anonymous function

one(); // outputs one
```

I hope that helps
:)

Comment: This fixed my issue where my .js files are inserted via an "include" statement and therefore the function name could not be changed.