# Two javascript files, which method calls first?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [use two same name method in different .js files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492636/use-two-same-name-method-in-different-js-files)

I have two .js files named 1.js and 2.js, both .js files have the method `display()`. 
On page load which .js files `display()` method is called? How to set on each time it has to call 1.js files `display()` method needs to call.

Comment: Btw, this is something you can easily test yourself. Include both files, call the function and see which result you get.

Answer (score 0):

> which .js files display() methos called ?

The second one that loads, because it overwrites the first one.

> how to set on each time it has to call 1.js files display() methos
>   needs to call.

I haven't got a clue what this means...

Answer (score 0):

Think of 1.js and 2.js as one big js file. The `display()` function should only exist once