# Creating 2nd html element in javascript deletes the first

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript code that dynamically creates a select box with data from a file. They are a bit big and I am going to try and move then to am external js rather in the HTML once everything is working ok. My problem is that it seems when I try to run the same script, on a different file of course, it clears out the info from the first script. So I wind up with one select element populated and one blank. the last script is the only one that holds, which is why I think it is somehow clearing out the first one. Any suggestions. I am buidling up a menu so I needs this code to be modular. Thanks in advance.

*** UPDATE ***
I have split out the processcsv file and I still get the same results. In each fall of the function i am passing a different select element. On the webpage I will only see the last one execute with the select processed earliar rendered blank. I think the issue is the that my first xmlrequest never achieves readystate == 4 but the last one does. I am not sure what I can do to control that and why is it all but the last one that fails.

my html

```
<div class="menu_container">
    <div class="menu_element" id="plant_div">
        <select  class="Menu" id="plant_select">
        <script>     
             <!--var plant_select = document.createElement("select");  -->
             var datafile = '';
             var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

             xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost:8080/res/plants.csv",true);
             xmlhttp.send();
             xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
             {
                if(xmlhttp.status==200 && xmlhttp.readyState==4)
                {
                    processCSV(xmlhttp.responseText, plant_select,"select plant");
                }
             }
        </script>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="menu_element" id="plantType_div">
        <select  class="Menu" id="plantType_select">
        <script>
             <!--var plant_select = document.createElement("select");  -->
             var datafile = '';
             var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

             xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost:8080/res/planttypes.csv",true);
             xmlhttp.send();
             xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
             {
                if(xmlhttp.status==200 && xmlhttp.readyState==4)
                {
                    processCSV(xmlhttp.responseText, plantType_select,"select PLant Type);
                }
             }
        </script>
        </select>
    </div>

</div>
```

a seperate js file that contains

```
function processCSV(file,parentNode,defaultmessage)
             {
                var frag = document.createDocumentFragment()
                , lines = file.split('\n'), option;                 
                var intial_option = document.createElement("option");

                intial_option.setAttribute("value","");
                intial_option.setAttribute("disabled","disabled");
                intial_option.setAttribute("selected","selected");
                intial_option.innerHTML = defaultmessage;
                frag.appendChild(intial_option)

                for (var i = 0, len = lines.length; i < len; i++){
                    option = document.createElement("option");
                    option.setAttribute("value", lines[i]);
                    option.innerHTML = lines[i];                        
                    frag.appendChild(option);
                    }

                parentNode.appendChild(frag);
             }
```

Comment: Does `plant_select` really have an html comment wrapped around it?  If not, when is it ever added to the DOM?

Comment: Why is `processCSV()` duplicate?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown I was hoping the reuse the function for each select. I tried moving it out to its own js file but it still does not work.

Comment: @JamesMontagne the script sits in a select element with an id XXXX_select. So I had the stuff to the DOM via the append where the parentnode is that element explicitly in html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second function with the same name overwrites the first.

[Use two methods of the same name in different .js files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492636/use-two-methods-of-the-same-name-in-different-js-files)

Use unique function names, or just move the function out and call it twice.

```
function processCSV(file,parentNode) {...}

processCSV('/my/file/path', myParentNode);
```

Comment: is there anyway to make my script modular so I can use it mulitple times without resorting to func1 func2 func3 etc...

Comment: Sure. You just have to specify the arguments for each call. Answer updated.

Comment: I have done as you said and split it out and I have it passing a different parent node in the DOM. It still is wipingout what was done on the first call. Any ideas? I have updated my code above.

Comment: Nothing's jumping out at me, but it seems like you're still duplicating a lot of code.

Comment: I think i narrowed it down to the readystate never equalling 4. I am not sure why it will not work when I have two calls but will work with only 1. IS my code bad for loading the file ?

Answer (score 1):

You are never selecting the element to which you want the items added. Pass `document.getElementById(idOfParentNode)` to `processCSV` each time you're calling it. You don't need to have the calls inline in the `select` tags, either.

(That is, plant_select and  plantType_select aren't currently being defined to anything in your code shown)

And, because you're doing all the javascript we can see in the global scope, those variables are all attached to window.... which means you're stepping on your xmlhttp object by re-initializing it. Consider encapsulating more into better-factored functions in a single script block.

Comment: I think you are on to something with the xmlhttp statement. My first one never really completes but my second one does. Is there anyway to fix that? And what do you mean by encapsulate more?